# When and where to create a new action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using [carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) my users can now upload avatars of themselves! Yay! Here's my update action:

```
  def update

    @image = @user.create_avatar(file_name: user_params[:avatar][:file_name])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update_attributes(user_params.delete avatar: [:file_name]) # this automatically deletes any avatar instances, as uploaded files are saved in a seperate model
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

And here's my form:

```
<%= form_for(@user, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :avatar do |f| %>
        <%= f.file_field :file_name %>
        <%= f.submit %>
    <% end %> 
<% end %>
```

However, the above action blows up when someone isn't uploading an avatar, because, firstly, the `user_params` has no `:avatar` key, so calling `[:file_name]` results in an undefined method for nil error.

I could easily get around this with conditionals, but should I create a seperate action for updating my avatars? `def avatar_update` maybe? I'm just not sure of the best rails way to do this, as I have a seperate Image model, but I don't feel like such an action should go in the images controller because the user model has this relation:

```
has_one :avatar, class_name: 'Image', foreign_key: :user_id
```

To me, it literally feels like an `avatar_update` action "belongs" somewhere between the users controller and the images controller, so I really don't know where to put it. It would be RESTful to put it in the images controller, but the images model will, at some point in the future, belongs to many different models. That line of thinking would result in several actions in the images controller along the lines of `avatar_update` and `photo_update` and `panorama_update`, `post_image_update` and all kinds of things for my app's different types of images.

So where should I put my `update_avatar` action?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe despite having images associated with multiple models, all your image uploads will be similar enough that you can keep one `update` action in the images controller.  This action would update the image, then redirect to the `#show` page of whatever the associated record is. Imagine images can belong to users, articles, or albums:

```
class ImagesController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def update
    if @image.update_attributes(image_params)
      redirect_to @image.associated_record, notice: 'Image was successfully updated.'
    else
      render action: 'edit'
    end
  end
end


class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...

  def associated_record
    user || article || album
  end
end
```

The other possibility is that depending on which model it is associated with, each image `#update` action will be very different. In that case, make multiple `ImageController`s, namespaced under their associated models, each with their own `#update` action.  For instance:

```
# in app/controllers/users/images_controller.rb
class Users::ImagesController < ApplicationController
end

# in config/routes.rb
resources :users do
  resources :images, controller: 'users/images'
end
```

Source: The book Rails AntiPatterns: Best Practice Ruby on Rails Refactoring, chapter on 'Rat's nest resources'